# UITAbleView - эффект padding слева у разделителя

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Как заставить разделитель ячеек занимать всю ширину UITableView (чтобы не было визуального эффекта отступа от левого края)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В iOS7**

в интерфейс билдере ставите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если не сработает добавляете к таблице:

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

и к ячейке:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

**В iOS8**

в ячейке:

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Если вы поддерживаете и 7 и 8, помните, что два метода указанные выше доступны только в iOS8. По этому проверяйте доступны ли эти методы перед использованием. Что то вроде:

```
if([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)]) {
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```